# Swift JSONDecoder loses special character from string

Tags: json, swift

I have a JSON object, which has the key value:
"content":""

Actually, the value of content is 7 BOM characters, you can copy it into SublimeText to view it.
But when I use the command in the Swift:

```
let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)
```

then **object.content** only has 6 characters.

Do you know why and how to fix it?

This full example shows the issue:

```swift
import Foundation

let bom: Character = "\u{FEFF}"
let string = String(repeating: bom, count: 7)
print(string.count) // 7

let json = #"{"content": "\#(string)" }"#.data(using: .utf8)!

struct Type: Decodable {
    let content: String
}

let decoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Type.self, from: json)
print(decoded.content.count) // 6
```

One of the special characters is lost during JSON parsing.

Comment: You’ll need to provide more context than this. Please provide a minimal replicable example with code so that we can see what is happening and try and help.

Comment: I have added a reproducible example to the question, it should not be closed.

Comment: The character is not valid in JSON and gets ignored at the beginning of the string.